# Terry tao intro to measure theory note prologue excersise 25

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $[a,b]$ be an interval and $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Prove that f is riemann integrable if and only if $E_{+} = \{(x,t): x \in [a,b]; 0 \leq t \leq f(x)\}$ and $E_{-} = \{(x,t): x \in [a,b]; f(x) \leq t \leq 0\}$ are both jordan measurable in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Here's the link [terry tao prologue](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/245a-prologue-the-problem-of-measure/)

I'm drawing a blank here. I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Hint: the value of the integral would be the Jordan measure of $E_+$ minus the Jordan measure of $E_-$. Do you see the relevance now?

Comment: The point is that $E_+$ is the positive region under the curve, and so both the Riemann integral and Jordan measure attempt to approximate this area by boxes.

Comment: I think I see where it's headed. I'm thinking of the boxes used in the upper and lower sums.